# Error encounter using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem about PHP and MySQL. I write information to MySQL database, but `"ü,ö,ğ,ç,ş,"` letters change to `Ã§ÅŸÃ¶ÄŸÃ¼Ä±É™`.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: What's the character set of the table you are trying to write to?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an encoding problem.

Try `utf8_encode()` function.

You may wanna refer to this:  [utf8_encode() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Hope this helps.